# Use rel="nofollow" on internal ads?

Tags: seo, advertising, nofollow

I know you're supposed to use rel="nofollow" on outgoing ads, to keep from passing link juice, but what about internal ads? We have a number of links with pictures that I consider as ads to other parts of our site (usually to a sub-domain). Should I rel="nofollow" them? With google's most recent algorithm change this month, I feel like some things have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should always avoid* using use `rel="nofollow"` on internal links. Matt Cutts [wrote about this](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/) a while back.

Of course, things might change in the future, but as of today, that's Google's advice.

*As per @Mike's comment, "avoid" is a bit strong - "don't bother with" is probably more suitable.

Comment: you've taken Matt Cutts's statement "I wouldn't recommend it" and transformed it into "should always avoid". I'm pretty confident that it was a recommendation, not a *rule*. There are PLENTY of reasons to use no-follow on internal links (links to dead-end pages, login pages, forced-order anchor-text linking etc), but for most webmasters it's not of any concern.

Comment: @Mike Perhaps 'should always avoid' is a bit strong in the sense that it's not going to get you booted off Google. But Matt Cutts is clearly saying that rel="nofollow" on internal links is at best pointless, and can harm your SEO by 'evaporating' your PageRank. Pages that you don't want indexed should just be listed in your robots.txt.

Comment: I guess we are not going to agree some interpretations, but that's half the fun. Also, I would recommend `meta robots="noindex, follow"` rather than `robots.txt`, as it has been shown that `robots.txt` doesn't prevent *indexation*, just *crawling*.

Comment: @Mike Hmmm, interesting I hadn't noticed that before. Useful link should someone need it: http://www.seobook.com/robots-txt-vs-rel-nofollow-vs-meta-robots-nofollow